# Mobile app prototyping tools

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7, mobile

What are few of the best mobile prototyping tools, and what is the best approach to mobile prototype

I would like to create something code free at first and then start design more stuff with the same or more advanced tool.

Answer (score 7):

Try this [article](http://blog.stephengates.com/2012/06/28/best-design-tools-mobile-design/) it describes the best design tools for mobile design.

Also you can use more powerful tools:

- [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/)
- [Proto.io](http://proto.io/)

Comment: This article is a joke if you ask me. It's neither complete nor makes much use - just a few apps for use when you care iOS.

Comment: Proto.io - no spinners for Android.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using [Justinmind Prototyper](http://www.justinmind.com/prototyper/download), the UI is very close to what is on device and provides a good feel to the end-user about the application overview and flow.

Comment: Justinmind is most advanced tool for PROTOTYPING. Other tools like Balsamiq are only for mocking.

Answer (score 2):

Would add fluidui.com to the mix, drag and drop with full iOS, Android and Win8 Libraries, or upload your own images and ability to test transitions and interactions live on a phone (via QR code scan)

Answer (score 2):

I'm developer of [MockingBot](https://mockingbot.com), we recently launched a new version with brand new design, i think you should give it a try.

[image]

Comment: I like it but there is no spinner, radio buttons and checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its a bit too late but I just released http://www.protocoder.org under MIT license, give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

- [MockFlow](http://www.mockflow.com/)
- [Tiggzi](http://appery.io/)

Really like the Mockflow. Got a free to use plan for a fast little project and only 69$ for a year to use it in business. I think its possible to set up a GUI Design in something like a year. For any Changes you got Photoshop(Gimp) ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://xiffe.com

It has a drag and drop interface and support for app workflow simulation by linking screens through button clicks. Supports iOS, Android and Windows Phone.